# How to draw custom positions of items in CheckbosList in Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
// How to draw where I want that Item to be
private static int topOffset = 30;
private static int leftOffset = 30; 

private void FoldersToClearItem_Position(string item)
{
    Point newPosition = new Point(leftOffset, topOffset);
}

// Making directories and setting checkedBoxlist1 items. Checkedboxlist item is renamed to FoldersToClear
private void ZzCleaner_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.FoldersToClear))  
    { 
        Properties.Settings.Default.FoldersToClear.Split(',') 
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(item =>
                    {
                        bool checkbox = false;

                        if (!FoldersToClear.Items.Contains(item))
                            FoldersToClear.Items.Add(item);

                        if (Properties.Settings.Default.CheckedFolders.Contains(item))
                        {
                            checkbox = true;
                            FolderOrganiser folderOrganiser = new FolderOrganiser(item, richTextBox1);
                        }
                        var index = this.FoldersToClear.Items.IndexOf(item);

                        FoldersToClear.SetItemChecked(index, checkbox);
                    });
    }
}
```

So I've been struggling to get a solution of how to make a new position to item in checkbox.

Below is code that gets information about what checkboxes were marked when program closed, and then they get the same items back as well.

My question is how would I put them a bit from border so let's say I want them `|` here make a little bit of space between checkbox and item?

Comment: You aren't drawing anything.  Was your previous question resolved?

Comment: Yes, it works amazing now. But here I have a question how to draw this, or move the elements.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.